# Do fenugreek tablets increase stamina and assist in weight loss?

Tags: weight-loss, herbalism

Recently I was told, by a friend, that taking [fenugreek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenugreek) tablets would increase stamina and assist in weight loss.

I am unsure of this claim. I had a quick look on Google but there is a lot of (contradictory) information.

Is there any scientific basis for this claim?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not enough evidence for this claim, according to the NIH:

> **What the Science Says**
>
> - A few small studies have found that fenugreek may help lower blood sugar levels in people with diabetes.
> - There is not enough scientific evidence to support the use of fenugreek for any other health condition.
>
> **Sources**
>
> Fenugreek. Natural Medicines Comprehensive Database Web site.
>   Accessed at www.naturaldatabase.com on August 18, 2009.
>
> Fenugreek
>   (Trigonella foenum-graecum L. Leguminosae). Natural Standard Database
>   Web site. Accessed at www.naturalstandard.com on August 13, 2009.
>
> Fenugreek seed. In: Blumenthal M, Goldberg A, Brinckman J, eds. Herbal
>   Medicine: Expanded Commission E Monographs. Newton, MA: Lippincott
>   Williams & Wilkins; 2000:130–133.

[National Institutes of Health : Herbs At A Glance : Fenugreek](http://nccam.nih.gov/health/fenugreek)

Comment: This is a secondary source, and provides only vague references to support its claims. It would be better to link to those studies.

Comment: While the National Institutes of Health is a secondary source, they are a well respected institution and I think their summary would be reliable than my own. The sources section seems fairly complete, so hopefully someone with more medical knowledge can use it to produce a better answer.  I've updated the answer to include the sources.

Comment: @ColinPickard : The question doesn't ask whether there's "enough scientific evidence to support the use" but asks for whether there's scientific basis. Drugs that are in phrase 3 clinical trials usually do enter those trials because there a scientific basis for believing that they work. At the same time those drugs don't have enough evidence to support their use by FDA standards. The standards of the NIH are unclear. As a result it's useful if you link to the concrete studies to summarize the evidence that's there instead of copying someone's judgement of "enough".